# Show entire legend even when a category is not displayed in the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I am working on a graph to show the hitting patterns of baseball players.
The location on a grid corresponds to where the ball was hit, and the colour of the circle corresponds to the outcome (single, double, triple, home run, out, sacrifice fly).

I am repeating this graph for multiple players, but not all players have a hit in all categories.

I ensured that the outcomes are labeled in the same colour (otherwise it would be confusing if homeruns were green for one player and outs were green for another player).

I would like to show a legend which includes all outcomes (single, double, triple, etc) even for graphs that are not plotting every one of those outcomes.  It would be useful for the person viewing this to recognize that a specific player has no home runs for example.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

```
#ggspraychart (data = correa, fill_value = "events")
spray_chart <- function(...) {
  ggplot(...) +
    geom_curve(x = 33, xend = 223, y = -100, yend = -100, curvature = -.65, color = "#36521A") +
    geom_segment(x = 128, xend = 33, y =-208, yend = -100, color = "#36521A") +
    geom_segment(x = 128, xend = 223, y =-208, yend = -100, color = "#36521A") +
    geom_curve(x = 83, xend = 173, y = -155, yend = -156, curvature = -.65, linetype = "dotted", color = "#36521A") +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_x_continuous(NULL, limits = c(25, 225))+
    scale_y_continuous(NULL, limits = c(-225, -25))
}


spray_chart(PlayerNF_events, aes(x = hc_x, y = -hc_y, color = events)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  labs(
  title = PlayerName,
  subtitle = "Regular season 2019 vs TB")+

  scale_color_manual(values = c("single" = "#DBA92A", "doule" = "#D98327", "triple" = "#CF5423", "home_run" = "#DE2723", "field_out" = "#3D5A5C", "sac_fly" = "#48475C")) +

  theme(
    # Remove panel border
    panel.border = element_blank(),  
    # Remove panel grid lines
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    # Remove panel background
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    # Add axis line
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: We don't have your data, so we can't run your code, and we can't see any output, so the best anyone can do is guess as to what you're looking at. I'd recommend also paying attention to the _minimal_ part of [mcve]: it's easier to help (and for you to debug) when you pare the question down to just what's needed to recreate the problem. My guess is that you should just add `drop = FALSE` to your color scale. You also seem to have misspelled "double" in your color scale.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Good catch with the "double".  I was able to strip it back to the basics and solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that might work for your data: add a layer whose data has all the outcomes, but hide the layer by making it transparent (`alpha = 0`), making its values `NA`, etc.

```
iris_s <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa")
ggplot(iris_s, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "#DBA92A", 
                                "versicolor" = "#3D5A5C", 
                                "virginica" = "#CF5423")) +
  # Either of these should work
  # geom_point(data = iris, alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(data = dplyr::mutate(iris, Sepal.Width = NA_real_))
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  I ended up creating a "dummy" with all of the values, then setting to NA_real_

Answer (score 1):

This builds on the example data by @Jon Spring but uses `tidyr::complete` to make sure all factor levels in the column of interest (here `Species`) are explicitly missing instead of implicitly missing (i.e are there and have NA and will therefore be included in plot legend).

This is better than using the entire data as plotting transparent data can be slow, it also means that the axis limits are set by the data you are plotting not by the entire data.frame.

```
iris_s %>% tidyr::complete(Species) %>% 
ggplot(., aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("setosa" = "#DBA92A", 
                            "versicolor" = "#3D5A5C", 
                            "virginica" = "#CF5423"))
```